Commander tax on mutate?
Otrimi, the Ever-Playful dies and returns to my command zone. I want to cast him again, using his mutate ability. Do I have to pay the commander tax?

Yes, mutate costs increase by the commander tax.
Mutate is an alternative cost. You otherwise cast the commander the same way as you would cast it normally.

702.140a Mutate appears on some creature cards. It represents a static ability that functions while the spell with mutate is on the stack. “Mutate [cost]” means “You may pay [cost] rather than pay this spell’s mana cost. If you do, it becomes a mutating creature spell and targets a non-Human creature with the same owner as this spell.” Casting a spell using its mutate ability follows the rules for paying alternative costs (see 601.2b and 601.2f–h).

The commander tax is an additional cost that is applied whenever you cast your commander from the command zone, whether you cast it through its normal mana cost, or its alternative mutate cost:

903.8. A player may cast a commander they own from the command zone. A commander cast from the command zone costs an additional {2} for each previous time the player casting it has cast it from the command zone that game. This additional cost is informally known as the “commander tax.”

Additional costs are applied to alternative costs the same way they are applied to mana costs:

118.9d If an alternative cost is being paid to cast a spell, any additional costs, cost increases, and cost reductions that affect that spell are applied to that alternative cost. (See rule 601.2f.)


Yes, you [most likely] do have to pay the commander tax.
The amount you have to pay doesn't take into account any game state changes other than how many times you previously cast your commander from the command zone.

903.8. (...) A commander cast from the command zone costs an additional {2} for each previous time the player casting it has cast it from the command zone that game. This additional cost is informally known as the "commander tax."

Technically, there are ways in which you could have put the commander on the battlefield without casting it before, such as via Command Beacon, but in that case, the reason why you don't have to pay the commander tax isn't in any way related to Mutate, or anything else that happened - it's only ever the amount of times you cast it before.
